# Normalize nested object with AbstractNormalizer::ATTRIBUTES

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, normalization

I have an object "Cliente" that has a nested object (among other fields) called "Responsavel" and then inside it another object called "usuario".
I'm creating a custom normalizer to return the data for me as an json, I have this so far:

```
    public function normalize($cliente, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        // $data = $this->normalizer->normalize($cliente, $format, $context);
        $data['clienteId'] = $cliente->getId();
        $data['clienteCodigo'] = $cliente->getCodigo();
        $data['clienteRazao'] = $cliente->getRazao();
        $data['clienteRegistro'] = $cliente->getRegistro();
        $data['responsaveis']= [];
        $responsaveis = $cliente->getResponsavel();
        foreach($responsaveis as $responsavel){
            array_push($data['responsaveis'],$this->normalizer->normalize($responsavel, $format, [AbstractNormalizer::ATTRIBUTES => ['id', 'competenciaInicial','ativo', 'usuario']]));
        }
        
        
        return $data;

    }
```

I'm using the AbstractNormalizer to say what field I want returned but when I get to the 'usuario' I don't know how to call the ATTRIBUTES i need form inside of it, like usuario['id'] for example. I've found this on symfony's git

> /**
> * Limit (de)normalize to the specified names.
> *
> * For nested structures, this list needs to reflect the object tree.
> */

How can I achieve that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it [selecting-specific-attributes](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#selecting-specific-attributes)!

When selecting attributes from a nested object you ned to do it like `[AbstractNormalizer::ATTRIBUTES => ['flatAttr', 'nestedOject'=>['flatAttrFromNestedObj']]]`